# Password generator prints no values even though it should print the password created

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

When I tested the code below through:

```
PWD = create_password(4, 5, 8, 10, 72, True)
show_created_password(PWD)
```

there wasn't any values printed. I used `yield` at first but then after the problem happened, I tried `return` but the problem still occurred. How can I fix this problem?

*Original code:*

```
"""
Generator Module for Password Manager
"""
# Imports
from passwordmeter import test
from random import choice, randint
import string_utils

# Generator
words = open('words.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
special_chars = ['!', '?', '%', '$', '*', '(', ')', '&', '@', '#', '^', '+', '=', '-', '_', '"', ';', ':', '<', '>', '/', '\\']
uppercase_letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L''M','N', 'O', 'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

def create_password(num_words, num_numbers, num_special, num_uppercase_words, char_limit = 0, Strengthen = False):
    """
    Generates Pasword from words, Uppercase letters, special chars, and numbers with the options of:
    :param num_words: Number of Words in password.
    :param num_numbers: Number of numbers in password.
    :param num_special: Number of Special Characters in password.
    :param num_uppercase_words: Number of uppercase words in password.
    :param char_limit: Limit of characters in password.
    :param Strengthen: Strengthens the password.
    """
    #TODO Connect the arguments with wx for user customization.
    pass_str = ' '
    if char_limit > 0:
        while True:
            if len(pass_str) == char_limit:
                if Strengthen == True:
                    pass_str = string_utils.shuffle(pass_str)
                    pass_str = pass_str.replace(" ", "")
                    yield pass_str
                else:
                    yield pass_str
                break
            else:
                for _ in range(num_words):
                    pass_str+=choice(words).lower().capitalize()
                for _ in range(num_numbers):
                    pass_str==str(randint(0,100))
                for _ in range(num_special):
                    pass_str+=choice(special_chars)
                for _ in range(num_uppercase_words):
                    pass_str+=choice(uppercase_letters)
    else:
        for _ in range(num_words):
            pass_str+=choice(words).lower().capitalize()
        for _ in range(num_numbers):
            pass_str+=str(randint(0,100))
        for _ in range(num_special):
            pass_str+=choice(special_chars)
        for _ in range(num_uppercase_words):
            pass_str+=choice(uppercase_letters)
        if Strengthen == True:
            pass_str = string_utils.shuffle(pass_str)
            pass_str = pass_str.replace(" ", "")
            yield pass_str
        else:
            yield pass_str
         
def show_created_password(created_password):
    """
    Shows password generated by generator
    """
    for value in created_password:
        pass_str = value
    strength,_=test(pass_str)
    #TODO make print statements into wx form in the mainapp.py file or through a different wx method
    print('\nPassword: %s'%pass_str)
    print('Strength: %0.5f'%strength)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, forget about `yield`, use `return`. `yield` is used to make an special type of functions that can be run several times and give the output in several steps. For example, I could have a `primes` function implemented with `yield` so that every time I call it, it gives me the next prime number:

```py
def primes():
    for n in (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19):  # Instead of this you would actually compute the numbers
        yield n

prime_numbers = primes()
next(prime_numbers)  # 1
next(prime_numbers)  # 2
next(prime_numbers)  # 3
next(prime_numbers)  # 5
next(prime_numbers)  # 7
```

The issue you have is that the `while True` loop will never end. The only way to end that loop is with the `break` and that code is only executed if the length of the pass and the character limit are exactly equal, which most probably won't happen as you are adding a lot of characters every iteration. Imagine you add 50 characters each iteration and your limit is 75. First iteration the condition is False (length 0, limit 75) so we add 50 characters. Second iteration the condition is False (length 50, limit 75) so we add another 50 characters. Third iteration is False (length 100, limit 75) so we add another 50 characters. You will be iterating forever and the limit will never be the same as the length, which will keep growing until you run out of memory.

The `show_password` also has an error. When you pass the created password you are passing a string. So you need to remove the loop. I think you have this loop because you were using `yield` incorrectly.

```py
def create_password(num_words, num_numbers, num_special, num_uppercase_words, char_limit = 0, strengthen = False):
    """
    Generates password from words, uppercase letters, special chars, and numbers with the following options:
    :param num_words: number of words in password
    :param num_numbers: number of numbers in password
    :param num_special: number of special characters in password
    :param num_uppercase_words: number of uppercase words in password
    :param char_limit: limit of characters in password
    :param strengthen: strengthens the password
    """
    # TODO: Connect the arguments with wx for user customization.
    pass_str = ''.join(
        [choice(words).lower().capitalize() for _ in range(num_words)] + 
        [str(randint(0,100)) for _ in range(num_numbers)] + 
        [choice(special_chars) for _ in range(num_special)] + 
        [choice(uppercase_letters) for _ in range(num_uppercase_words)]
    )

    if strengthen:
        pass_str = string_utils.shuffle(pass_str)
        pass_str = pass_str.replace(' ', '')

    if char_limit > 0:
        pass_str = pass_str[:char_limit]

    return pass_str


def show_created_password(pass_str):
    """
    Shows password generated by generator
    """
    strength, _ = test(pass_str)
    #TODO make print statements into wx form in the mainapp.py file or through a different wx method
    print("Password: {:s}".format(pass_str))
    print("Strength: {:0.5f}".format(strength))
    print()
```

In the first place, you do not need any loop if it is a char limit, you would need a loop if you had a minimum length, but a char limit just requires to make sure to cut it at the end if it is too long.

`Strengthen` should not be used as a variable, parameter or function name, Title-case names are reserved for class names, I changed it to `stregthen`.
I changed all the loops you had that added to the password into list comprehensions of the form `[SOMETHING for _ in range(SOMENUMBER)]`. This creates a list with that number of elements. I then added all the lists to merge them into a single list, which I later join by the empty string `""`. Basically this concats all items in the list into a string.
Once we have the string, we check if we need to strengthen it, and then we check if we are above the limit to cut it down.
After that, we can return the password.

The other method is mostly the same, removing the loop, but I used the `"Hello {}".format("world!")` way, which I recommend you to use instead of the `"Hello %s"%"world!"`.

Comment: How would I be able to fix the `create_password_function`/ I have this so far: https://hasteb.in/sexobaca.py

Comment: @DawnChopin I edited to add the functions, will add some explanation now